# SocketException when connecting to VM Service

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running a flutter application using WSL2 and adb. The emulator is running on the Windows side.

The application was built successfully, but it gives me the following error:

```
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused,
errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 43678
```

In Vscode, it doesn't even build.

Logs:

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might
have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific
port known to be available.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused,
errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 43378
This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
```